# How I can see the width & height of my window on the "body" when I am modifying the size of the window with jquery?

Tags: jquery, windows, resize

I need show the width & height with jquery in the red zone of the picture...

How I can do that?

THE IMAGE https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37666311/Captura-de-pantalla-2013-07-06-a-las-10.40.57.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/5ANZz/1/

```
$('#width').val($(window).width());
$('#height').val($(window).height());

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#width').val($(window).width());
    $('#height').val($(window).height());
});
```

Comment: But when I change the size not refresh the size of  in the "input", infact not show the size...

Comment: Great!! Thank you..it works.. Could do you explain me how works?

Comment: .width() and .height() returns the element's width and height. You want window' width and height, that is why, i used window as element. And $(window).resize(function(){} detects window width/height changes. More detail...http://api.jquery.com/width/ ,http://api.jquery.com/height/, http://api.jquery.com/resize/